# Can I share data between sibling components in this case?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-props

Is there a way to share data between sibling components without the need to return the component from which I need the data? here is an example to explain it better:

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <div>
          <h1>Home page</h1>
          <Component1 />
          <Component2 />
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

const Component1 = (props) => {
  const importantInfo = "secret-info";
  if (props.handleInfo) {
    props.handleInfo(importantInfo);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <p>I am component number 1</p>
    </div>
  );
};

const Component2 = () => {
  const handleInfo = (info) => {
    console.log(info);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <p>I am component number 2</p>
      <Component1 handleInfo={(info) => handleInfo(info)} />
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

I want to use some data from `Component1` in `Component2`. The only way I found to do this, was to return the `component1` inside the `component2` and put the `props` in there.

I mean this:

```
return (
    <div>
      <p>I am component number 2</p>
      <Component1 handleInfo={(info) => handleInfo(info)} />
    </div>
```

Is there a way not to return the component and still receive the data throw `props`? I know I can do it with `UseContext` and with other methods, but I want to know if I can do it with props. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is creating a new state in `App.js` as the following:

```
function App() {
   const [commonInfo, setCommonInfo] = useState('information')

   return // rest of the code
}
```

Then pass that down through `props` in both components as:

```
return (
  <div className="App">
    <header className="App-header">
      <div>
        <h1>Home page</h1>
        <Component1 commonInfo={commonInfo} setCommonInfo={setCommonInfo} />
        <Component2 commonInfo={commonInfo} setCommonInfo={setCommonInfo} />
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
);
```

Thus you can destructure from `props` in the components as the following:

```
// and also in Component2
const Component1 = (props) => {
   const { commonInfo, setCommonInfo } = props

   // rest
}
```

Comment: And what if I dont want to create an state in App? is there a way to pass props through functions and not returning the component? (I am asking the same question of the post)

Comment: are you opposed to using context?

Comment: you could store the props in context and pass them that way, I believe that would be the best solution.  I am unsure of any other way to pass props to another component without it being in the return